# How do I remove a shortcut in Textmate?

Tags: browser, keyboard, textmate, shortcut

Whenever I hit CMD + R in TextMate (version 1.5.11), it opens Safari.

How do I disable that shortcut, or at least make it open Chrome instead?

Couldn't find anything on TextMate preferences, neither on system preferences's application shortcuts.

Comment: Is this really a programming-related question?

Comment: Ask on http://superuser.com/ instead